# Why 1024 "bytes" make one kilobyte...isn't it 1024 bits make one kilobyte

Tags: byte, bit

If 2^0 is 1 bit and 2^1 is 2 bits then why 2^10 is called one kilobyte but not one kiloBIT.
As 8 bits are equal to one byte then 1024 bIts are 128 bytes not 1024 bYtes.

And if one kilobyte is equal to 1024 bytes then this should be 1024*8= 8192 bits, no?

Comment: 8 bits to a byte, 1024 bytes to a kilobyte. 1024 bits would be one kilo*bit*, 1024 bytes is one kilo*byte*. So, as you stated, 1 **kilobit** = 125 bytes. Also voting to close.

Comment: There is such thing as a kiloBIT. Your ISP measures throughput in kiloBITs. KB is kilobytes, kb is kilobits.Not voting to close.

Comment: @MattClark 
If 1024 bytes = 1KB , to me this means 1024*8 = 8192 bits = 1KB 
==
2^13 = 1KB  is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its actually pretty simple:

```
2^3 bits = 1 byte
2^10 bits = 128 bytes
1000 bits = 1 kilobit
1000 bytes/1024 bytes = 1 kilobyte (kB = 1000 bytes/ KB = 1024 bytes)
```

Comment: So 2^10 = 128 bytes and is not equal to one kilobyte. 2^13 = 1 kilobyte.
I got it now, thanks